# What is the best way to pass an Excel range to a user defined function?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, user, range

I pass a big range from an Excel spreadsheet to the parameter ExcelRange of a user-defined function (UDF) written in VBA.

1. I can declare the parameter ExcelRange As Range and then convert it to Variant:
   Dim VariantArray As Variant
   VariantArray = ExcelRange.Value2

or

2. I can directly declare the parameter ExcelRange of the UDF as Variant.

In either case, inside a loop, I will convert each element of VariantArray or ExcelRange to a Double variable.

Which is more time-efficient, 1. or 2.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In either case, inside a loop, I will convert each element of VariantArray to a Double variable.
>   Which is more efficient, 1. or 2.?

As you convert your range to Variant anyway, I don't see a big difference in performance.
Whether you convert and then pass OR pass and then convert should just take the same effort.

The difference comes in the use of your UDF:

- if you need to do anything with the range (e.g. get the address), then obviously you need to take a Range argument
- if you expect users to pass arrays, not a Range, then it is better to declare the argument as a Variant (e.g. `=SUM({1,2,3})` is a valid formula in Excel).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Have you timed the alternatives inside a big loop?

Comment: You stated you'd convert to Variant array both cases BEFORE THE LOOP. why would there be any difference during the loop?

Comment: I would like to time the two procedures inside a big loop just to repeat each procedure a big number of times so as to have a good sample estimate of the difference between the two procedures. If I knew how to do it, I would run each big loop a few times, and pick the smallest time for each procedure, just in case the computer gets distracted with another procedure at some point.